# Is storing value over multiple bytes undefined?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

Okay, so I have written a memory allocator which works like a stack. It consists of a character array which is my memory. When I allocate memory I basically return a pointer (cast to void *) to a bit of free memory and then I increment a pointer which keeps track of where the next bit of free memory is by the amount of bytes I asked for.

Freeing is just as simple, I just make the pointer which keeps track of the next bit of free memory point to where it pointed before I allocated some memory. It is basically a stack.

When I cast the (void *) to an (int *) it takes that memory and then spreads that integer over the elements in my character array. Now, I was wondering if this causes undefined behaviour? I think it has to do with big-endian and little-endian. Here is some code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1024

unsigned char buffer[BUFSIZE];
unsigned char *next = buffer;

void *alloc(int n){
    if(next + n <= buffer + BUFSIZE){
        next += n;
        return (void *)(next - n);
    }else{
        return NULL;
    }
}

void afree(void *c){
    next = (char *)c;
}

int main(){
    int *num = (int *)alloc(sizeof(int));
    *num = 346455;
    printf("%d: %d\n", *num, sizeof(int));
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d", *(next - 4), *(next - 3), *(next - 2), *(next - 1));
    afree(num);
}
```

All that main does is that it asks for some memory and then sets the value of that memory to an integer. My first printf-statement also works just fine! It prints the integer correctly and also prints out the amount of bytes an integer takes up.

My second printf-statement is a bit more interesting though; it prints out all of the four bytes that the integer is built up of: 87, 73, 5, 0. If I then, with these numbers (in reverse order), take their binary values and stick them together and convert that big binary number to decimal, I get my original int. So, as I previously said: Does this cause undefined behaviour or does it always work **as intended**?

Comment: You're assuming `sizeof int == 4`, which is not necessarily true on every platform.

Comment: BTW, regardless of the actual question, `printf("%d: %s\n", *num, sizeof(int));` is most definitely UB (since `sizeof(int)` does not point to a properly allocated null-terminated string of characters).

Comment: It has nothing to do with endianness; it has a lot to do with alignment.  You need to ensure that the pointer you return is suitably aligned for any use.  That means you should not, in general, return an odd-numbered value, for example.  You can't store a `double` except on a multiple of 8 (occasionally 4) bytes.

Comment: Finally, in order to ensure correct alignment for every possible storage unit on your platform, you need to make sure that function `alloc` returns a pointer whose integral value is a multiple of `sizeof size_t` on our platform.

Comment: First, don't cast the `void*` in C, it adds no value -- it's an implicit conversion as far as the type system is concerned and a no-op when it comes to the output. Second, on its own, using the bytes of an object as an array of `unsigned char` isn't UB, as far as I know (I recall reading about this quite recently, actually). Third, a scalar type in C has both storage and alignment requirements -- you have taken care of storage but failed to take care of alignment right now. Fourth, the thing you're doing with pointers at the final `printf` would be safer to do with a union (possible aliasing).

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, however, I just want to emphasize that I know that my assumption about the amount of bytes a value takes up isn't 4 on every platform, I have just done this assumption to make it easier for me, of course I wouldn't use this in an actual program.

Comment: @barakmanos That was just a mistake on my part from when I edited the code here on stackoverflow, my actual code still says %d (I edited the code just to cut out some unnecessary clutter). Sorry for that, fixed.

Comment: Let me reiterate what Jonathan Leffler said about alignment.  Your biggest issue is that "odd numbered" addresses are generally not suitable for storing multibyte quantities.  So in general you need to round `next` up to an even multiple of `n` before allocating an object of size `n`.

Comment: @SteveSummit How would I go about doing that?

Comment: The discussion about odd addresses is okay, but processors can have no alignment requirement at all, or it can be more than 2 bytes. 8-byte alignment for double is pretty common. Additionally, bigger alignment block can improve performance even when a smaller one will work.